# Disable submit button when form is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I validate with jQuery Validate.  I want to be able to disable the submit button when the form is invalid but I am unsure of the best approach.  To disable the button I can simply do this

```
$("#clientConfigurationForm input[type=submit]")
     .prop("disabled", !clientConfigValidation.valid());
```

The issue is where do I put this code? It seems that the only way to track all changes is to replicate the code in both `unhighlight` and `highlight`.

Is there a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: Why don't you put that code into a function and call the function in different places? I don't see anything wrong with replication then - the code is in one place and the function calls can be in many.

Comment: Think about this for a minute... what's the initial state of the button when the page is first loaded?  The button is not yet disabled, but an empty form is technically invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd execute it when an input is changed.

```
$('#yourForm input, #yourForm select, #yourForm textarea').on('change', checkForm);

function checkForm(){
    $("#clientConfigurationForm input[type=submit]")
        .prop("disabled", !clientConfigValidation.valid());
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `blur` instead of `change` - with `change` you would have to assume that the form is perfectly valid when the page is initialy loaded and there are no changes to inputs.

Comment: Problem with this is that when you get into complicated forms, where checkboxes can enable and disable form components then a simple `change` or `blur` no longer works. I was hoping there would be something built-in that could handle this.

Comment: @Chris but all the logic of validation is in `clientConfigValidation.valid()`, isn't it? If so, it should be ok to call the function on each element blur or change - they just fire the check and don't have to care about validation logic.

Comment: This doesnt entirely work, because if I enable and disable a checkbox then the form inputs disable and then become enabled again, at this point `clientConfigValidation.valid()` says `true` but, on submit, it realises its not actually valid... Very odd

Comment: What was the problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP's Comment:**

> *"This doesnt entirely work, because if I enable and disable a checkbox then the form inputs disable and then become enabled again, at this point clientConfigValidation.valid() says true but, on submit, it realises its not actually valid... Very odd"*

This is caused by a timing issue regarding when the value of the checkbox actually changes.

To fix it change your `change` event into a `click` event to more immediately capture your checkbox and radio buttons.  This does not seem to alter how the rest of the input elements behave, because you have to `click` on them when you `change` them.

```
$('input, select, textarea').on('click', checkForm);

function checkForm(){
    $("input[type=submit]")
        .prop("disabled", !($('#clientConfigurationForm').valid()));
}
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/8umJ6/

---

If you notice any issues with one input type over another, you could tweak the code by specifying different events for different input types.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').on('click', checkForm);

$('input[type="text"], select, textarea').on('change', checkForm);

function checkForm(){
    $('input[type="submit"]')
        .prop("disabled", !($('#clientConfigurationForm').valid()));
}
```